# Running a script in R for several individuals in a study

Tags: r

I'm a Master's student in animal behavior, very beginner in R. I'm doing statistics for my thesis and decided to give R a try before I resort to PSPP, after a small introductory course I had on the language, using R Studio.

I wrote a very basic script that

1. Imports data from 51 individuals from a csv. file, and also imports a csv. file to store results in.
2. Creates a subset with data from one individual and then, depending on the data, makes a hypothesis, runs a binomial test and decides whether the hypothesis is rejected or not. The hypothesis, p-value of the binomial test and rejection/acceptance of hypothesis per individual are stored in the results file.

The script is fully functional when I run it for each individual. I apologize in advance for the bad quality of the code, but here's the script for one individual, if you'd like to take a look:

```r
## Import data and results file
odor_behavior <- read.csv("odor_behavior.csv")
percalf_binomial_odor_results <- read.csv("percalf_binomial_odor_results.csv")

# Create binomial dataset per calf (example here: 958)
pref958 <- subset(odor_behavior, Calf_ID == 958, c("Preference"), drop=FALSE)

# Count the number of testing sessions for this calf
n958 <- nrow(pref958)

# Calculate how many times a suckling behavior appears (Control=1 or Modified=3).
mat958 <- as.matrix(pref958)
fmat958 <- factor(mat958,levels=c(1,3),ordered=TRUE)
fpref958 <- table(fmat958)
data958 <- as.data.frame(fpref958)

# Hypothesize a preference according to the observations and save it. 
# Also, save variables for the binomial test.
## Find the row in which to store the results
row958<- which(percalf_binomial_odor_results$Calf_ID == 958)
## Decide the hypothesis. 
  if (data958[1,2] > data958[2,2]) {
    x958 <- data958[1,2]
    percalf_binomial_odor_results[row958,c("H_preference")] <- "Control"
  } else if (data958[1,2] < data958[2,2]) {
    x958 <- data958[2,2]
    percalf_binomial_odor_results[row958,c("H_preference")] <- "Odor"
  } else if (data958[1,2] == data958[2,2]) {
    x958 <- data958[1,2]
    percalf_binomial_odor_results[row958,c("H_preference")] <- "Either"
  } else {print("Check your data, Maria!")
  }


# Run binomial test
binom.test (x=x958, n=n958, p=0.5, conf.level = 0.95)

# Save the p.value and decide whether the hypothesized preference is real or not
pbin958 <- binom.test (x=x958, n=n958, p=0.5, conf.level = 0.95)$p.value
percalf_binomial_odor_results[row958,c("Bin_odor_pvalue")] <- pbin958
  if (pbin958 <0.05) {
    percalf_binomial_odor_results[row958,c("Real_preference")] <- "Yes"
  } else {
    percalf_binomial_odor_results[row958,c("Real_preference")] <- "No"
  }
```

As mentioned, it all runs smoothly when I repeat the script for each individual, by copy-pasting the code and manually changing the "Calf_ID" fifty times.

**The question:** Is it possible for the script to run by itself for each individual? I have tried doing it by placing all 51 "Calf_ID"s in a matrix, and putting the script in a function that uses the elements from the matrix to go through each individual.

*Lapply* returns correct results, but only with regard to whether the hypothesis was accepted/rejected (ie last part of the script), which has me thinking that the script indeed runs for all 51 individuals. However, no results get stored in the respective file during the process (highly likely because I am doing something wrong in the first place). When I do the manual copy-paste/edit procedure, all results (hypothesis, p-value and result for hypothesis per individual) are correctly stored in the results file.

I'm able to get my results by the copy-pasting method; It's simply a question of efficiency, because right now I have 51 individuals, but what does one do when they have one thousand? It would be great to know how to make it work!

**EDIT**
As requested in the comments, here are the results (after running the script for individual 958) to

> **dput(head(odor_behavior)):**
>   structure(list(Calf_ID = c(958L, 958L, 958L, 958L, 958L, 958L), Preference = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L)), .Names = c("Calf_ID", "Preference"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

and

> **dput(head(percalf_binomial_odor_results)):**
>   structure(list(Calf_ID = c(958L, 7015L, 7017L, 959L, 7018L, 7019L),
>   H_preference = c("Control", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Bin_odor_pvalue = c(0.453125, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Real_preference = c("No", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Calf_ID", "H_preference", "Bin_odor_pvalue", "Real_preference"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

**UPDATE**
Here is another example on the same topic, based on the answer @alexis_laz provided for the initial script. In this case, I am importing a data set of 3 columns (Calf_ID, Control_time, Odor_time), that includes several control and odor time measurements for a given Calf ID (like with preferences, in the initial example). The script tries to conduct a Wilcoxon signed-rank test for the Control_time - Odor_time pair, for each Calf_ID. Here is how the script looks:

```
    ### Import data and load library with test
odor_times <- read.csv("odor_times.csv")
library(coin)

### Create a function that examines suckling preference
prefanalysis <- function(Control_time, Odor_time)
{
  sessions <- length(Control_time)

  #Run a Wilcoxon signed rank test. Set y ~ x as control and odor, 
  mypvalue <- pvalue(wilcoxsign_test(Control_time ~ Odor_time))
  myzvalue <- statistic(wilcoxsign_test(Control_time ~ Odor_time))

  #Decide if there is a true difference in suckling times according to p value, and save it
  true_diff <- if(mypvalue < 0.05) "Yes" else "No"

  # Create a data frame with hypothesis, p value and real preference
  data.frame(sessions, myzvalue, mypvalue, true_diff, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

### Run the function for all calves, with preference depending on calf ID. Save results.
results <- as.data.frame(do.call(data.frame, aggregate(cbind(Control_time, Odor_time) ~ Calf_ID, odor_times, prefanalysis)))
```

In this case, I am receiving the following error:

```
     Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  argument "Odor_time" is missing, with no default
```

When rerun with Debug, I can see that the script starts reading Control_time correctly for the first individual (ie for the rows with a specific Calf_ID). However it seems unable to do the same for Odor_time. I cannot (for the life of me) see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Creating functions and calling them with lapply are probably the key to your problem. To have some reproducible data could you share the results of `dput(head(odor_behavior))` and `dput(head(percalf_binomial_odor_results))` ([edit] your question to add them)

Comment: rstudio has an "extract function" that worked okay for this example. basically you can `f <- function(id) {# code here replace "958" with "id"}` and the last line will be what is returned so maybe for you it is `list(p.value = pbin958, results = percalf_binomial_odor_results)`. then use `lapply`

Comment: It seems that your script performs an operation like (not detailed as your script) `aggregate(Preference ~ Calf_ID, odor_behavior, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = c(1, 3), labels = c("control", "modified"))))` -- i.e. you apply a function by a group. So you could built a function -say `f`- that accepts "Preferences" and returns a result and use it as `aggregate(Preference ~ ID, odor_behavior, f)` or any similar group-by function (e.g. `tapply`, `by`, `lapply(split(what, by), f)`) or packages with such functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you apply computations to "Preference" grouped by each "Calf_ID". Instead of subsetting `odor_behavior$Preference` repeteadly for each id, we could utilize R's group-by functions after, first, building a function that performs all work given appropriate input.

I tried to simplify your script in a function -- hopefully I've not missed hard to accomodate details:

```
ff = function(pref)
{
    fx = factor(pref, levels = c(1L, 3L), labels = c("Control", "Odor"))
    tab = table(fx)

    p = binom.test(max(tab), length(pref), p = 0.5, conf.level = 0.95)$p.value

    real_pref = if(p < 0.05) "yes" else "no"
    H_pref = if(tab["Control"] == tab["Odor"]) "Either" else names(which.max(tab))

    data.frame(p = p, real_pref = real_pref, H_pref = H_pref, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

And, then, apply it for all "Calf_ID" individuals:

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(pref ~ ID, dat, ff))
#   ID     pref.p pref.real_pref pref.H_pref
#1   1 0.07295139             no     Control
#2   2  0.1689778             no     Control
#3   3  0.8919232             no        Odor
#4   4  0.6029232             no        Odor
#5   5          1             no     Control
#6   6  0.7659918             no     Control
#7   7          1             no        Odor
#8   8   0.889884             no     Control
#9   9          1             no      Either
#10 10  0.5758493             no     Control
```

where `dat` is:

```
set.seed(1821)
dat = data.frame(ID = sample(10, 500, TRUE), pref = sample(c(1L, 3L), 500, TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you @alexis_laz, I have now tested it with my own data and it works like a charm. I added a couple of lines to put the results in a data frame and save it in a csv. file.

Comment: @MariaMalidaki : Glad I could help. This falls under the general "split-apply-combine" concept on "long" data. You could follow links/examples in `?aggregate` and `?split` and, also, packages like "data.table" and "dplyr" which are widely used on current topics. BTW, note that `lapply`, in contrast to a `for` loop, does not have side effects, so assiging to variables inside of `lapply` is less straightforward than a simple loop. E.g. compare `x = numeric(5); for(i in 1:length(x)) x[i] <- i; x` VS `x = numeric(5); lapply(1:length(x), function(i) x[i] <- i); x`

Comment: On the same topic, I have tried to edit your excellent code to work for two variables in the function, this time for a Wilcoxon test. I have updated the post in case you'd have any idea what I am possibly doing wrong. No pressure about it, you have already helped more than enough.

Comment: @MariaMalidaki : `aggregate` is not flexible to functions with more than one argument. You could use its workhorse: `split` and `lapply`. Here, it should be something like `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(odor_times, odor_times$Calf_ID), function(x) data.frame(id = x$Calf_ID[1], prefanalysis(x$Control_time, x$Odor_time))))` where `odor_times` is separated based on "Calf_ID" and `prefanalysis` is applied separately on the appropriate columns of each sub-"data.frame".

Comment: Thank you @alexis_laz. I was ready to ask about perhaps using `split`, and you confirmed my thoughts!